# Disable vertical scroll and only allow horizontal

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I've recently switched to SwiperJS, which I've been happy with. There's one thing I would like to work, but I can't seem to work it out. When scrolling vertical on a slider it changes the slide, which makes it hard to scroll past the slider and further down or up the page. I would like to restrict it to only change slide when scrolling horizontal (like the feature on Apple macs).

I've tried with the code below without the desired result:

```
mousewheel: true,
forceToAxis: true,
```

I've also tried CSS, but that didn't work either.

```
touch-action: pan-x;
```

Is there anything built-in I can use or is it something custom?

I'm using the core Swiper version 10.2.0.

Thanks in advance!